# Server Setup for iPhone Push Notifications

Tags: iphone, python, ruby-on-rails, push-notification

I'm new to the whole push notifications thing, and was wondering if somebody could walk me through the process of getting a simple application up and running. I currently rent a server that I use to serve my website that runs cPanel X.

How would I go about setting up the service? What software do I need to install on the server? How do I upload code to the server?

Sorry if these are really dumb questions - I'm not really a web developer.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would go to the [Apple Developer Forums](http://devforums.apple.com).  They have many questions and answers regarding this.  For my apps, I use a Ruby On Rails plugin called [apn_on_rails](http://github.com/markbates/apn_on_rails), but this is probably not an option for you on a shared host with some sort of admin gui.  Your shared host probably runs php so I would look for a php implementation.